# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB s

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

**Hola gente! Tengo un error al enviar mis datos y he visto bastantes cosas para intentar solucionarlo pero no este es el error:**

> Error: INSERT INTO usuario(name,last,nameDad,nameMom,tipoIdentificacion,identificacion,telefono,email,address ,born,rango,estadoC,sex,contraseña) values ('sdasda','asdasd','asdasd','asdasd','Venezolano:','123123123','123123123123','dsdsdssd@gmail.casc','asdsd','19999-02-21','dsadasdasd','Soltero(A)', 'Man','sdsdsdsd')
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) values ('sdasda','asdasd','asdasd','asdasd','Venezolano:','123123123','12' at line 2

*y este es mi codigo php, cualquiar otra cosa que necesiten(CODIGO ETC), me avisan gracias!*

```
<?php 
 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "clini";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
 
if(!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
 ?>
 
<?php 
 
 $nombre = $_POST['name'];
 $identi = $_POST['ci'];

//Login
if(isset($_POST["ingre"]))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND identificacion='$identi'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if($nr==1)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Bienvenido: $nombre,$appelidoC:'); window.location='home.php' </script>";
    }else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario no existe '); window.location='index.php' </script>";
    }
}
  
  //Registrar
$name = $_POST["name"];
$apellido = $_POST["apec"];
$dad = $_POST["namep"];
$mom = $_POST["namem"];
$tipeCI = $_POST["tipeid"];
$ci = $_POST["ci"];
$phone = $_POST["te"];
$correo = $_POST["email"];
$add = $_POST["dirre"];
$day = $_POST["diana"];
$gradoI = $_POST["gradoin"];
$esC = $_POST["estado"];
$sex = $_POST["sex"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
  
if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(name,last,nameDad,nameMom,tipoIdentificacion,identificacion,telefono,email,address
    ,born,rango,estadoC,sex,contraseña)
    values ('$name','$apellido','$dad','$mom','$tipeCI','$ci','$phone','$correo','$add','$day','$gradoI','$esC',
    '$sex','$pass')"; 
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Feliciddes el usuario fue registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='index.html' </script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Parece que el nombre de columna `contraseña` te esté dando problemas, el error apunta a la `ñ` específicamente. En general no deben usarse caracteres especiales como nombre de tablas, columnas, variables, funciones...en fin, en nada que sea código. Dan problemas. Intenta cambiar ese nombre por otro y vuelve a intentarlo.

Comment: Si la columna usa caracteres especiales usa *backtick*: `\`contraseña\``.

Comment: Pero yo no he usado lo Ñ

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: ya preguntaste esto y se cerro por duplicada.. y si.. usaste la ñ en el campo contraseÑa... eso es una ñ, no?